# (Jassertfalse) JUCE Message Thread (1): EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: xcode, audio, plugins, juce

I'm trying to create a VST plug-in using JUCE framework but I've been having this error:
JUCE Message Thread (1): EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102e61424. This error comes up in correlation with red underlined "Jassertfalse".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK118.png)

Until then written Code:

```
juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout SimpleEQAudioProcessor::createParameterLayout()
{
    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("LowCut Freq",
                                                           "LowCut Freq",
                                                           juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f),20.f));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("HighCut Freq",
                                                           "Highcut Freq",
                                                           juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 20000.f));
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Freq",
                                                           "Peak Freq",
                                                           juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 750.f));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Gain",
                                                           "Peak Gain",
                                                           juce::NormalisableRange<float>(-24.f, 24.f, 0.5f, 1.f), 0.0f));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Quality",
                                                           "Peak Quality",
                                                           juce::NormalisableRange<float>(0.1f, 10.f, 0.05f, 1.f), 1.f));
    
    juce::StringArray stringArray;
    for( int i = 0; i <4; ++i)
    {
    juce::String str;
    str << (12 + i*12);
    str << " db/Oct";
    stringArray.add(str);
}
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>("LowCut Slope", "LowCut Slope", stringArray, 0));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>("HighCut Slope", "HighCut Slope", stringArray, 0));
    
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: For JUCE I would head to the [JUCE forum](https://forum.juce.com). From the looks of your error, I would deselect AudioUnit in Projucer if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the the [official documentation](https://docs.juce.com/master/classAudioProcessorParameter.html#a843462756ec916e5ba137677f30010e5) of the JUCE framework, when adding parameters you have to enclose the IDs in a way similar to this: `juce::ParameterID(param, 1)`.

Therefore, your code becomes this:

```
juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout SimpleEQAudioProcessor::createParameterLayout() {
    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>(juce::ParameterID("LowCut Freq", 1), "LowCut Freq", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 20.f));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>(juce::ParameterID("HighCut Freq", 1), "HighCut Freq", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 20000.f));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>(juce::ParameterID("Peak Freq", 1), "Peak Freq", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 750.f));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>(juce::ParameterID("Peak Gain", 1), "Peak Gain", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(-24.f, 24.f, 0.5f, 1.f), 0.0f));
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>(juce::ParameterID("Peak Quality", 1), "Peak Quality", juce::NormalisableRange<float>(0.1f, 10.f, 0.05f, 1.f), 1.f));
    
    juce::StringArray stringArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        juce::String str;
        str << (12 + i * 12);
        str << " db/Oct";
        stringArray.add(str);
    }
    
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>(juce::ParameterID("LowCut Slope", 1), "LowCut Slope", stringArray, 0));
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>(juce::ParameterID("HighCut Slope", 1), "HighCut Slope", stringArray, 0));
    
    return layout;
}
```